# Create, update, delete timestamps for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Given the following script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() < 11 ) { 
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+2:00", "dd/MM/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    s.getRange('L' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

It works perfectly fine. All I miss are two features:

1. Store a create timestamp in K column when the first edit was made;
2. Delete given timestamps if all rows are empty.

Comment: 1) First edit within the row's cell or row entirely? 2) Do you mean columns / cells within rows?

Comment: 1. row entirely.
2. r.getColumn() < 11 within the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() < 11 ) {

    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+2:00", "dd/MM/yy, hh:mm:ss");


    // 2. Delete given timestamps if all rows are empty.
    var values = s.getRange('A' + row.toString() + ':' + 'J' + row.toString()).getValues()[0]
    var filtered = values.filter(function (el) {
      return el != '';
    });
    if (filtered.length == 0) {
      s.getRange('A' + row.toString() + ':' + 'L' + row.toString()).clearContent();
    }

    s.getRange('L' + row.toString()).setValue(time);

    // 1. Store a create timestamp in K column when the first edit was made
    if (s.getRange('K' + row.toString()).getValue() == '') {
      s.getRange('K' + row.toString()).setValue(time);  
    }

  }
}
```